# Error in experimental verification of Newton's second law

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, experimental-physics, acceleration, error-analysis

I am doing a school lab to prove/derive Newton's Second Law from observation data that includes the force, mass, and acceleration.

We are told to plot these variables accordingly, I already know $F=ma$, however, there appear to be some errors in my lab.

**Error #1:**
The measured mass of a moving object is $0.503\ \mathrm{kg}$. Knowing $F=ma$, the mass should be the slope of $F$ vs $a$ graph. However, the slope of the trendline is $0.751$, a little bit too off.
[image]

**Error #2**: This graph is $F$ vs $ma$. Knowing that $F=ma$, the slope of this graph should be $1$. Again, it's a bit off.

[image]

**Error #3:** This graph is $a$ vs $m^{-1}$. The slope unit is $\frac{a}{m^{-1}} = ma = F$. The force measured during the experiment is $0.196\ \mathrm{N}$, but the slope shows $0.148$, a little bit better but is still off.

[image]

So in conclusion, is my lab data correct? Does it mean that Newton's Second Law, $F=ma$ is not always perfect (due to air resistance, frictions, or other common factors in physics that may affect final calculation)?

Comment: It think it's safe to include $(0,0)$ on the graph, though that may introduce question on the consistency of the methodology if it is unmeasurable with the equipment. It should at least be investigated. If it totally changes the result, you have a problem.

Comment: Without seeing the experimental setup, how you measured your data etc., it is impossible to tell where your error is.

Comment: @josephh The question I want to ask is that is F=ma perfect for all scenarios. Forget about the lab, just in the real world: Is this equation perfect or is it only approximate due to air resistance, etc?

Comment: Ah ok. See my answer below then.

Comment: Almost all results in physics are stated with errors on them since physics is at its heart an empirical science, it's really a matter of how large the error is. If you ran a linear regression analysis on the data you'd get some numbers that would tell you your deviation in the slope (LINEST in excel). Just looking at the numbers for the slopes doesn't tell you the whole story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So in conclusion, is my lab data correct? Does it mean that Newton's Second Law, F=ma is not always perfect (due to air resistance, frictions, or other common factors in physics that may affect final calculation)?

It depends on what you mean by "perfect." Newton's second law is used in the engineering of any moving device: rockets, Mars rovers, submarines, airplanes, race cars, electron beams in microwave ovens, and uncountably many others. The engineers who use $F=ma$ expect it to give precise and accurate results in all cases. So, you should expect that equation to give exact results. Even though one experiment can disprove a scientific idea like Newton's Laws, there have been so many tests of Newton's Laws over centuries that it would be a better use of time to examine your experiment to find the source of the discrepancy.

Now, when you say that Newton's second law is "not always perfect" due to factors like air resistance and friction, you are saying that you want to ignore other forces. The full statement of Newton's second law is
$$\Sigma F = ma$$
where the sigma ($\Sigma$) means sum. So, if you add together all the forces on your object, you will get exactly the mass times the acceleration. To put it another way,
$$F_{applied} + F_{friction} + F_{air\ resistance} + F_{something\ else} + \cdots = ma$$
How large these other forces are depends on your specific experiment.

In your experiment, force, acceleration, and mass are all measured quantities and require careful analysis of your measurement techniques. As an example, I'm going to assume your experiment was the following:

1. A mass is mounted on an air track (like a one-dimensional air hockey table) to significantly reduce friction.
2. The force is provided by a hanging weight.
3. The hanging weight is attached to the mass on the air track by a string that goes over a lightweight pulley.
4. The acceleration is measured by timing how long the object takes to move a set distance. Assuming constant acceleration, the acceleration is $a=2x/t^2$.

Here are some common measurement errors from my lab courses:

1. Mass

   - For each mass, did you weight just the object itself or the mass of the object and the air track cart? Both have to be accelerated by the force.
2. Acceleration

   - How is the distance traveled defined? If you measure the starting point and the ending point of the cart on the track, did you measure the same location on the cart? If you measure when the front edge of the cart passes the start position and when the back edge passes the end position, the distance between the start and end is not the distance traveled. You have to measure the position of the same point on the cart at both locations.
   - How accurately can you start and stop the stopwatch that times the motion? Is there anything that could cause the stopwatch to start or stop at the wrong time?
3. Force

   - When you measure the mass of the hanging weights, are you measuring just the weights or the weights and the weight holder? It is the total hanging mass that provides the accelerating force.
   - Is the hanging mass swinging when it is let go? If the weight swings, then the force on the object will not be constant.

These are the kinds of questions you have to ask yourself whenever you run an experiment. In my own work, one of two things always happens:

- If I run an experiment and get a result that does not match with well-known equations, my first thought is, "What did I do wrong?"
- If I run an experiment and get a result that exactly matches well-known equations, my first thought is, "What did I do wrong?"

These are not contradictory. Even professional scientists do this. An important lesson to learn when doing science is that you should always doubt your results and look for errors. Only after this search and examination of your methods do you write your report. This is why even professional scientific papers have a Methods section to describe exactly what they did so readers of that paper can understand the measurement and have confidence that the measurement was done correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have no faults in any of your equipment, your data could be "correct" in the sense that you measured the forces and accelerations correctly, but because of friction and/or other dissipative forces, you did not obtain correct results.

If you had a situation where there was no friction, or any other kind of dissipation, then your results would have suggested that Newton's second law was exactly followed. For example, in your first graph the gradient would indeed be exactly equal to the mass of the object.

In real situations (if we ignore dissipative forces), the data would suggest that the equation for Newton's second law was not exactly followed.
But it is *very* important to note that Newton's second law $$F=\frac{dp}{dt}=ma$$ is an *exact* law. In systems where dissipation is very minimal (like in the orbit of planets) one can calculate how the system evolves over time with very high accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

*I am doing a school lab to **prove/derive** Newton's Second Law from observation data . . . . .*  is a rather bold statement as you are probably using the law when measuring the forces so perhaps illustrate is a better word?

To be able to properly comment on your results one would need to have details of the experimental set up that you used which are not apparent in your post.  For example, knowledge of the object being accelerated, how the frictional forces between the object and the ground are reduced, the method of applying (and measuring) the force etc would help with assessing your data.

No mention is made of errors and there are no error bars on the graphs so looking at graphs **1** and**2** are all five points equally accurate?  If the left hand point had a greater error than the rest then one could perhaps draw a best-fit straight line giving more weight to the right hand four points?

Often in this sort of experiment unknown friction forces can play a small but significant part.  In part one can compensate for them by arranging the apparatus, eg changing the slope of the track on which the object moves, so that with no experimenter applied force the object moves at constant velocity.  So change the angle of the track so that the object moves down it at constant speed and the frictional force is compensated for by the component of the weight of the object down the track.